# Access to ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm asking how we can acceed to an ObservableCollection.
Actually I'm working on a project and i have to collect the checked elements in an ObservableCollection in order to copy these elements to a PDF file.

```
public Class FianlElements
{
    private int chapAr;

    public int ChapAr
    {
        get { return chapAr; }
        set
        {
            chapAr = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ChaprAr");
            OnPropertyChanged("Article");
        }
    }

    private string article;

    public string Article
    {
        get { return article; }
        set
        {
            article = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ChapAr");
            OnPropertyChanged("Article");
        }
    }

    private float somme;

    public float Somme
    {
        get { return somme; }
        set
        {
            somme = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Somme");
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertySomme)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new 
            PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertySomme));
    }
}
```

Actually this is the class of the type of ObservableCollection
My declaration of the ObservableCollection is here

```
public ObservableCollection<FinalSelection> LesElem { get; set; }
```

I have another ObservableCollection

```
public ObservableCollection<ListBoxArticle> LesArticles { get; set; }
```

This one is Binded to a ListBox which contains CheckBox and TextBox 
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqnPL.png)
so I want to copy only the checked elements to "LesElem"

So how can I get access to this ObservableCollection
Thanx

Comment: I can't see any ObservableCollection in your code.

Comment: You have a class here with three properties:  an int, a string and a float.  What is it that you are trying to do?  Do you have a collection of these things?

Comment: Did you just miss an ObservableCollection<t> out your code or do you not know how to add one... or what? If you had one then you can use linq and a where clause to pick entries out
var checked = Pieces.Where(x => x.IsChecked == true).ToList();

Comment: I added some details

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let's imagine you are interested in LesArticle which are ticked.

AND

You have an IsChecked property on LesArticle.

AND

This is bound to the IsChecked property of the checkbox.

The list of checked ones would be

```
var checkedList = LesArticle.Where(x => x.IsChecked == true).ToList();
```

Observablecollection can take a List as it's constructor. So you can do:

```
FinalElem = new ObservableCollection<ListBoxArticle>(checkedList);
```

Comment: and how can I senf this List to my ObservableCollection <FinalElem>?

Comment: @Andy `checked` is a reserved keyword (I know it's just an example but you might want to change that)

Comment: I've edited my post. If you want to bind to FinalElem then you probably want to raise property changed on FinalElem when you set it.  By the way. You can use CallerMemberName to avoid "magic strings" for names of properties. Take a look at the documentation on msdn.

Comment: I tried this but the ObservableCollection FinalElem is empty! you have an idea why?

Comment: Check if ischecked ever really gets set to true and what you get in your list. Put a break point in, step through and examine your variables. Any binding failures in output window?

Comment: my ischecked is binding well, only the new observableCollection didn't get created

Comment: If it's binding ok and you checked some so you have LesArticles which have IsChecked==true then you'd have some entries in checkedList. If you had some then FinalElem would end up with some entries. One of these isn't happening. I can't step through your code so I only know what you tell me.

Comment: @Andy actually in my window i have a comboBox, when I select an item my ListBox will be updated with those checkboxes and textboxes, So i think that the problem is where to put this instruction, is it in Combo_SelectionChanged or in the main?

Comment: Sorry,but you've lost me with your explanation. I don't see how the listbox, checkbox and combobox fits together. I would usually bind selecteditem of a combo and act in the setter for that property.

Comment: GoodMorning @Andy, i have another question please. Now my ObservableCollection is being modified, but only with new elements, how can i save the old checked elements and add new checked elements?

Comment: Hi again. One question is supposed to be kind of contained and not step by step development. But. I guess you have checked stuff from some past process and checked stuff from some new. You could retain a reference to the last lot and append the new by iterating and using .Add() rather than new up the observablecollection each time. For further questions please start a new thread and include enough code and explanation so less people don't have to guess.( Hope this helps ).